# how to hide message "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required"?

Tags: debian

I get this message when I want to upgrade my packages

how can I hide this message?

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ant-contrib blender-data .....

Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an error, it's just information -- some packages in your system were previously automatically installed as dependencies and are no longer needed (for example because dependencies of a package you installed changed in a newer version).

You can remove these with `apt-get autoremove`. If you need some of the packages, you can tell apt to keep them using `apt-mark manual <package>` and apt won't show them in the future.

Edit: If you only want to hide the message, you can configure apt to not show it. You'll need to write `APT::Get::HideAutoRemove "1";` to apt config file. You can use following command to do that

```
echo -e 'APT::Get::HideAutoRemove "1";' | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90_display_unused
```

([Source](https://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2017/10/30/how-to-remove-unused-dependency-packages/))

Comment: got it, but my mean is hiding this message when I try to install the new package, at all I would not like to see this message at the starting of the installation process

Comment: Ok, I did a little googling and found solution to just hide the message -- I've updated my answer.

Comment: You made my day man, thanks

Comment: In addition, you can pass this option to a single command if you want to silence this message for something like a script, versus permanently silencing it.

`sudo apt-get -o=APT::Get::HideAutoRemove=1 install bash`